# How to get object element down?

Tags: jquery

I need to get the object `test2` when I click on the element `test1`

```
<ul> 
      <li id="test1"><a href="javascript: void(0);">Label one</a>
        <ul id="test2">
          <li><a href="test.php">test</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="test3"><a href="javascript: void(0);">Label two</a>
        <ul id="test4">
          <li><a href="test.php">test</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
</ul>
```

How do I get the object `test2` when I click on `li id="test1"` ?

Comment: Show us your JS code. Do you use jQuery?

Comment: They have ids.. so just use the `ID` selector `$('#test2')`

Comment: Its not clear, if you want to have click function on `li#test1`, then why using `a` tag? Do you want have the function on `a` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [$.children](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

```
$('li').click(function(){
  var $target = $(this).children('ul');
});
```

Comment: Why do everyone assumes jQuery to be present? :)

Comment: The only thing that you need to define somehow `li` elements of the first level. In the sample above it will attach event to all `li` elements including neseted.

Answer (score 2):

Using jquery:

```
$('#test1').on('click', function (e) {
    var test2 = $('#test2);
});
```

vanilla javascript:

```
var test1 = document.getElementById('test1');
test.addEventListener('click', grabTest2, false);

function grabTest2() {
    var test2 = document.getElementById('test2');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its better to identify the element by `class` instead of using `ids`. I have use `liClass` class for parent li and `ulClass` for child ul. This will `save` you from generating `lot of ids` and their manipulation and will not effect other li and ul on the page if you are using neigher class or id.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/pnAnc/)**

*Html*

```
<ul> 
      <li id="test1" class="liClass"><a href="javascript: void(0);">Детские коляски</a>
        <ul id="test2" class="ulClass">
          <li><a href="test.php">test</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="test3"><a href="javascript: void(0);">Детские коляски</a>
        <ul id="test4">
          <li><a href="test.php">test</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
</ul>
```

*Javascript*

```
$('.liClass').click(function(){
  obj = $(this).find('.ulClass');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to your top `ul` element

```
<ul class="test"> 
      <li id="test1">
          <a href="javascript: void(0);">Детские коляски</a>
          <ul id="test2">
              <li><a href="test.php">test</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="test3">
          <a href="javascript: void(0);">Детские коляски</a>
          <ul id="test4">
              <li><a href="test.php">test</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
</ul>
```

and then

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.test > li').click(function(){
            var childUl = $(this).children('ul');
            // do what you want with childUl
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to have function on click of `a` tag which is in `li`.

You need to have atleast one class defined.(or else include parent element like `div>ul>li>a`)

```
$('ul.parent > li > a').click(function(){
   var obj = $(this).parent().children('ul');  //going back one step and selecting the child element
});
```

check the [**fiddle**](http://jsbin.com/inaboq/1/edit)

If you want the click function on `li` itself then go with other solutions (or try to get by changing the above solution which I provided)

I am not sure about whether this is recommended or not.